# What does the Bitcoin Core wallet backup do?

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup

I set a password to encrypt my wallet, all good.  But I can't seem to backup my wallet.  I try and nothing happens.

Does the backup function give me keys or the seed words?

Answer (score 1):

It creates a copy of the wallet file.

Bitcoin Core doesn't support recovery from just a key or seed phrase (at least, not yet).

Comment: Thanks.  Any thoughts as to why it isn't creating any sort of backup file?

Comment: The copy it creates is the backup. If it doesn't, there is something wrong, but you'll need to give more details about what you're actually doing to figure that.

Comment: I tried it again.  When prompted to save I just created a name.  And it placed a backup.dat file in the folder.  Maybe that's all there is to it.  I didn't see how to restore it though in the file menu.

Comment: Yes, that's it. To restore it you place it in the data directory.